# Telnet to multiple cisco routers using Python expect script

Tags: python, networking, cisco

I cannot get the following script to work, even for the case when the login is successful or when log in is not successful.

1. What Regular Expressions can I use to accept all the prompts below?

   ```
   router1>;
   router3>; 
   router4#
   ```
2. How can I use a regular expression where I can expect all the text before "fail" and after the "fail" prompt and then at end I will get  >>> " permission denied

```
Current failed Login: ########
User Access Verification
Username: asdsad
Password:
% Authentication failed
Current Successful Login ###########
[root@localhost testuserpass]# telnet 192.168.1.31
Trying 192.168.1.31...
Connected to 192.168.1.31.
Escape character is '^]'.
User Access Verification
Username: admin
Password:
testname&gt;
testname&gt;
testname&gt;
testname&gt;
testname&gt;
```

My Script Below ################

Question about Cisco routers telnet login Regular Expressions

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pexpect
import getpass

HOST = "192.168.1.31"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = getpass.getpass()
child = pexpect.spawn ('telnet '+HOST)
child.expect ('Username: ')
child.sendline (user)
child.expect ('Password: ')
child.sendline (password)

//// ######I just can't get below part to work. 
i = child.expect (['*Authentication*', 'Terminal type', '[#\$&gt;] '])

if i==0:
    print('Permission denied on host. Can\'t login')
    child.kill(0)
    print child.readline()
elif i==1:
    print('Login OK... need to send terminal type.')
    child.sendline('vt100')
    child.expect('[#\$] ')
    print child.readline()
elif i==2:
    print('Login OK.')
    print('Shell command prompt', child.after)
    print child.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also struggling with many different scripting applications but finally found  PrettyGoodTerminal which can handle scripts smoothly. It is specifically designed to script Cisco routers, so you may also find it useful